# Class Conforming to Protocol with Optional Parameter - Swift

Tags: swift

The following code snippet is fine, but is it possible to omit the `isOnboarding` parameter from the `ContactsViewController` class?

That would mean `ContactsViewController` does not conform to `ErrorController`, but is there anyway around having to use a function with a parameter that isn't used in this case?

```swift
class ErrorViewControllerDelegate {}

protocol ErrorController {
   func showError(_ error: String, isOnboarding: Bool)
}

extension  ErrorController {
   func showError(_ error: String, isOnboarding: Bool = true) {
    showError(error, isOnboarding: isOnboarding)
   }
}

class ContactsViewController: UIViewController, ErrorController {
   func showError(_ error: String) {
    showError(error)
   }
}

let contacts: ErrorController = ContactsViewController()
contacts.showError("I don't need a delegate.")
contacts.showError("I need a delegate.", isOnboarding: true)
```

Goal: to use `func showError(_ error: String)` rather than `func showError(_ error: String, isOnboarding: Bool)` as the function to conform to `ErrorController` in `ContactsViewController`.

Comment: I might be wrong, but doesn't your code cause infinite recursion?

Comment: Yes, that's right. That's the issue. If you use func showError(_ error: String, isOnboarding: Bool) it functions as expected. But can it work with unc showError(_ error: String)?

Comment: Umm no? What exactly is your expected result? Right now you just have 2 `showError` methods, both of which calls another `showError` method. No matter how you change their signatures, it's not going to stop recursing. I suggest that you add some `print` calls, so that it is easier for you to describe the expected result (e.g. "I expect '...' to be printed")

Comment: Is there anyway around having to use a function with a parameter that isn't used in this case? I have working code,  but would like to know if I could improve it.

Comment: Yes there is but why are your functions calling themselves?

Comment: What you want isn't possible. Omitting parameters only works on the calling side of things, not on the conforming side of things.